# Python: Not able to parse the data to convert it into a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I have a task of extracting data for only specific time from many log files which are text files of the form:

```
Aug 15 17:32:57  sandbox_pre_process_config:[sandbox] Sandbox pre process
Aug 15 17:32:57  sandbox_list_destroy:[sandbox] sandbox_list_destroy, sandbox list destroy done
Aug 15 17:32:57  sandbox_list_create:[sandbox] sandbox_list_create, sandbox list create done
Aug 15 17:32:57  entering ext_mac_pre_process_config, init_done 1
```

I am able to extract the date, but I am not able to convert it to a datetime object which I need for further operation.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re

month_abbr = {"jan": 1, "feb": 2, "mar": 3, "apr": 4, "may": 5, "jun": 6,
              "jul": 7, "aug": 8, "sep": 9, "oct": 10, "nov": 11, "dec": 12}

def parse_date(lines):
    mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3)

    date_string = "{:02} {:02} ".format(month_abbr[mon.lower()], int(day)) + tim
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError as e:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")

f = open("temp.txt")
for lines in f:
    line = lines.strip()
    date_obj = re.search('(.*?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', line)
    if date_obj:
        date = date_obj.group(1)
        val = parse_date(date)
        print val
```

This is the error I am encountering:

```
Aug 15 17:41:06

Aug 15 17:41:07

Aug 15 17:41:07

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 23, in <module>
    val = parse_date(date)
  File "main.py", line 9, in parse_date
    mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I am not able to see what is wrong ! Please help me out !

P.S - Only standard python libraries can be used !

Comment: make it `mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 2)`

Comment: could you put `print(lines)` statement above the `mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3)`. This can give a clear idea for which data it is breaking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach should work:

```
from datetime import datetime        

with open("temp.txt") as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        data = line.strip().split(' ', 3)
        date_string = ' '.join(data[:3])

        for date_format in ["%b %d %H:%M:%S", "%b %d %H:%M:%S.%f"]:
            try:
                dt = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
                print dt, data[-1].strip()      # print date and log entry
            except ValueError as e:
                pass
```

It splits the first 3 spaces giving you the date and log entry components. It then joins the date parts back together and applies the two possible date formats. If one correctly parses the date, the entry is displayed, if not, the line is skipped.

`%b` is used to match the 3 letter month.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the input is **Aug 15 17:32:50 abc**

`lines.split(None, 3)` is splitting it into 4 parts while you are assigning only 3 variable.

Run the below code

```
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
import re

month_abbr = {"jan": 1, "feb": 2, "mar": 3, "apr": 4, "may": 5, "jun": 6,
              "jul": 7, "aug": 8, "sep": 9, "oct": 10, "nov": 11, "dec": 12}

def parse_date(lines):
    mon, day, tim, _ = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change

    date_string = "{:02} {:02} ".format(month_abbr[mon.lower()], int(day)) + tim
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S")
    except ValueError as e:
        return datetime.strptime(date_string, "%m %d %H:%M:%S.%f")

f = open("temp.txt")
for lines in f:
    line = lines.strip()
    date_obj = re.search('(.*?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)', line)
    if date_obj:
        date = date_obj.group(1)
        if date:
            val = parse_date(date)
        else:
            continue
        print val
```

Comment: File "temp.py", line 23, in <module>
    val = parse_date(date)
  File "temp.py", line 9, in parse_date
    mon, day, tim, _ = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Comment: could you add `print lines` above line 9? and give the output?

Comment: ['Aug', '16', '01:58:59', 'zfchip_hsl2_poll_intr_registers: ZF[1] int[0x0] int2_grp0[0x0] int2_grp1[0x0] int2_grp2[0x0]\n']
[]
['Aug', '16', '01:59:24', 'zfchip_hsl2_poll_intr_registers: ZF[0] int[0x0] int2_grp0[0x0] int2_grp1[0x0] int2_grp2[0x0]\n']
[]

Comment: I don't know why there is an empty list after some subsequent lines are run

Comment: I have updated the code, kindly try executing it and see.

Comment: ['D', 'release', '18.4I234567_0000_barney', 'built by barney on 2018-08-16 00:31:26 ABC\n']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    val = parse_date(date)
  File "main.py", line 10, in parse_date
    mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Got stuck here again

Comment: `mon, day, tim = lines.split(None, 3)` this is not the code I have written. kindly copy paste the code which is written in the answer. I have written `mon, day, tim, _ = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    val = parse_date(date)
  File "main.py", line 18, in parse_date
    mon, day, tim, _ = lines.split(None, 3)[:3]
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
    val = parse_date(date)
  File "main.py", line 9, in parse_date
    mon, day, tim, _ = lines.split(None, 3) # note the change
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how the text files look exactly, but the error you are getting means that the string splitter splits the log string into more than 3 parts (because the second argument of the split method is off by one - it will split it in 4 parts).

In case you don't want the text after the time to be assigned to a variable you can circumvent the number of splits to the first 3 elements with a slice index behind the stringsplitter as lines.split(None, 3)[:3]. But you have to make sure that every string from the log is build exactly the same way.